# Why do we need a template specialization for a template-template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Take as an example this code to determine the length of a type list:

```
template <class... Types>
class type_list {};

template <class TypeList>
struct type_list_length;  // <---

template <template <class...> class type_list, class... Types>
struct type_list_length<TypeList<Types...>>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(Types);
};
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/LRVHVL)

Why do we need the marked declaration? I tried to compile the code without it in several compilers but are always getting errors.

Comment: Because without a primary template we cannot write a specialization

Comment: But why do we need the specialization in the first place?

Comment: If you try to do it without the specialization, you'll get a good sense of why it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why do we need the specialization in the first place?

Because you use the `class` as follows

```
std::cout << type_list_length<type_list<int, long, long long>>::value;
// ...........................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- template argument
```

or also

```
std::cout << type_list_length<std::tuple<int, long, long long>>::value;
// ...........................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- template argumen
```

or in a similar way.

Observe the template argument: in both cases is a **type**; `type_list<int, long, long long>` in first case, `std::tuple<int, long, long long>`.

So you can't declare `type_list_length` as receiving a template-template type

```
template <template <class...> class type_list, class... Types>
struct type_list_length // <--- doesn't work
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(Types);
};
```

because you should call it passing a template-template parameter followed by a variadic list of templates; I mean... you should use it as follows

```
std::cout << type_list_length<type_list, int, long, long long>::value;
std::cout << type_list_length<std::tuple, int, long, long long>::value;
```

but, this way, you loose the power of the class: extract and count the template parameter of the type parameter.

So you need first declare `type_list_length` as receiving a type

```
template <typename> // no template parameter name needed here (not used)
struct type_list_length;
```

and then declare and define a specialization in case the received type is a template-template with arguments

```
template <template <typename...> class type_list, typename... Types>
struct type_list_length<TypeList<Types...>>
{ // ...................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   the parameter is a type
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(Types);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that without the primary template we cannot write a specialization.

The longer answer is: how would you extract `Types...` from the instantiation of a templated type without a specialization? You cannot.

Here's an attempt:

```
template <template <class...> class type_list, class... Types>
struct type_list_length
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(Types);
};
```

We can do this:

```
type_list_length<type_list, int, double, float>::value
```

But not this:

```
using MyListType = type_list<int, double, float>;
type_list_length<MyListType>::value;
```

Because our template expects a template-template parameter and some types, so we're forced to accept just a single type to match `MyListType`:

```
template <class T>
struct type_list_length
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = // ????;
};
```

But now we're faced with another issue. How do we assign `value`? We need some way to extract the template arguments for `MyListType`, or at least the count.

We need a way to match a single type **and** the arguments it is templated on. Hence, we need match just a single type AND its template parameters.

```
template <class TypeList>
struct type_list_length; 

template <template <class...> class type_list, class... Types>
struct type_list_length<TypeList<Types...>>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(Types);
};
```

The first (incomplete) type is our primary template. It allows us to start matching a single type, like `MyListType`.

The second (complete) type is our specialization. it allows us to match a single type AND if it's a templated type, match the types used as template parameters for it.

By leaving the first type incomplete, we demonstrate our intention to ONLY allow the specialization to be valid.

Comment: I think my problem in understanding this is: why can the compiler instantiate the specialization if the primary template is present but not if it is missing? I mean it still _expects a template-template parameter and some types_ and we are still giving it a single type.

Comment: OK, I think I got it now. The primary template tells the compiler that this template accepts just a single type and the specialization can than "define" certain "requirements" on that type to get instantiated.

Comment: @sigy: Right! With a class there's just no way to go from a template template type plus types into a single type with just a primary template. If we were writing a function, we could do that, though [for example](https://godbolt.org/z/z5RqvP)